# Adding $ sign into the textfield when the user enter in the field

Tags: java, swing, textfield

Anyone know how to  auto add $ sign into the textfield when the user enter in the field and also       disable the user from cancel the $ sign.

Comment: What, so you're not accepting the British Pound, Euros, Dirhams, Shekels..?  How very exclusionist of you!  I think I'll spend my hard earned Dirhams elsewhere..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Let's not forget Indian Rupees

Comment: @LittleChild  Oh of course not..  I was just getting started!  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 2):

Not "strictly" what you're asking, but start by taking [How to use for attend text fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html), for example...

```
paymentField = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance());
paymentField.setValue(new Double(payment));
paymentField.setColumns(10);
paymentField.setEditable(false);
```

The problem with this is it's possible for the user to remove the `$` sign and the validation is very strict, meaning that the text entered into the field MUST start with a `$`

Another possibility is to use the `BuddySupport` API from Swing Labs, SwingX library

[image: BuddySupport]

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
paymentField = new JFormattedTextField(nf);
paymentField.setValue(100d);
paymentField.setColumns(10);
paymentField.setEditable(false);
BuddySupport.addLeft(new JLabel("$"), paymentField);
```

This means that that `$` is a separate component from the actual field and can't be removed by the user (but is contained within the field so it is not affected by the parent container's layout manager)

Comment: There is a `JFormattedTextField` ? WOW ! xD

Comment: @LittleChild The problem with this, is it won't strictly meet the OP's requirements as the user can delete the $ sign...but, the `NumberFormat` will take into account the symbols used by the locale ;)

Answer (score 1):

> The java.awt.TextField could be monitored for changes by adding a
>   TextListener for TextEvent's. In the JTextComponent based components,
>   changes are broadcasted from the model via a DocumentEvent to
>   DocumentListeners. The DocumentEvent gives the location of the change
>   and the kind of change if desired.

You need to use the [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) and combine it with some `Regex` to do the magic. If the text at a given point does not match the format you want, do not update the `JTextField` *or simply using the `.charAt()` method would do but then it is up to you*

**SSCCE** *without DocumentListener*

```
package stack;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class OhMyDollar {

    static JFrame frame;
    static JTextField field;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                frame = new JFrame("Useless Title");
                field = new JTextField("$", 30);
                frame.getContentPane().add(field);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                field.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
                        StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer(field.getText());
                        StringBuffer dollar = new StringBuffer("$");
                        if(field.getText().isEmpty() || text.charAt(0)!='$'){
                            field.setText(dollar.append(text).toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `KeyListener`?  A better solution would have being to go for a `DocumentFilter` personally...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Looking up `DocumentFilter`. Can't blame a man for trying it with `KeyListener`! I know it wont consider cut-copy-paste xD

Comment: [MDP's Blog](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for examples, [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for details ;)