# How to add button in text field?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I'm creating a text field in java using swing components. I want to make a search text field like one appears in Mozilla or other browsers.

I have added a button in text field. I have set border layout of `JTextField`. everything is working fine but whenever large text is written in text field (as it reaches the given size of text field) it goes behind the button. As everyone of you must have seen, this does not occur in search bars.  Text must not go behind the button rather there must be some gap between button and text.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Show us your code. Without that it's hard to help you

Comment: What layout are you using??.. I guess you are not using setBounds() method correctly

Comment: As @Markus said, Post your code..If possible attaching screenshot would be better...

Comment: There's a border trick you can use, no code to hand, or you could just use the BuddySupport API from SwingLabs, SwingX library, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578568/java-swing-listen-an-action-in-a-text-field-of-a-form/20578601#20578601) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495886/adding-sign-into-the-textfield-when-the-user-enter-in-the-field/21496102#21496102)

Comment: Or [ComponentBorder](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/component-border/)

Comment: sorry for late reply guys I just saw all your comments and answers..... I used BorderLayout ............
.......thanks to all of you guys ...........  eitanfar's code helped me out ............... :)

Comment: well here is my code:  JTextField field=new JTextField();


field.setSize(250, 30);


  field.setColumns(10);

  field.setLocation(5, 30);

  field.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  
  JButton button=new JButton("B");
  button.setSize(50, 20);
  button.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
  button.addActionListener(this);
  button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  button.setBounds(50, 50,50, 50);
  field.add(button,BorderLayout.EAST);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe start with something like this:

[image]

The blinking cursor is positioned at the far right of the text field.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

class ButtonsInTextField {

    JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JTextField textField;

    ButtonsInTextField(int cols) {
        JPanel textFieldWithButtonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(
                SwingConstants.LEADING, 5, 1));
        textField = new JTextField(cols);
        textFieldWithButtonsPanel.add(textField);

        addButtonToPanel(textFieldWithButtonsPanel, 8);
        addButtonToPanel(textFieldWithButtonsPanel, 16);
        addButtonToPanel(textFieldWithButtonsPanel, 24);

        // WARNING:  Not sensitive to PLAF change!
        textFieldWithButtonsPanel.setBackground(textField.getBackground());
        textFieldWithButtonsPanel.setBorder(textField.getBorder());
        textField.setBorder(null);
        // END WARNING:  

        gui.add(textFieldWithButtonsPanel);
    }

    private final void addButtonToPanel(JPanel panel, int height) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                // find the size of an icon from the system, 
                // this is just a guess
                24, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        JButton b = new JButton(new ImageIcon(bi));
        b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        //b.setBorderPainted(false);
        b.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        panel.add(b);
    }

    public final JComponent getGui() {
        return gui;
    }

    public final JTextField getField() {
        return textField;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ButtonsInTextField bitf = new ButtonsInTextField(20);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bitf.getGui());
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best way to do this. Don't mess with inserting a button as a child component of a text field, it's very difficult to get it right, and has virtually no benefits. This answer is very complete and explanatory, I would have voted it up twice if I could :-) Way to go !

Answer (score 0):

As people have noted above, it might have helped to see the code, especially the Layout manager.
However, you might try the following (if you haven't yet):

1. Call setColumns
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#setColumns(int)
2. Call setPreferredSize /setMaximumSize/setMinimumSize depending on your layout manager.
   But I'd try to avoid this solution because it's pixel-level maintenance.

Regards

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution you can use a [Component Border](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/component-border/), which allows you to use the button as a Border so it appears within the text field.